Webserver to forward and decrypts HTTPS to HTTP
Is it possible with Apache or Nginx (or others) to have the webserver configured for HTTPS/443 and translationg every request to simple HTTP and forwarding it to another process (just understanding HTTP, no HTTPS)
(HTTPS-Request) -> (HTTPS-Webserver) -> (HTTP-Server)

So it should not redirect the clients request to another server but passing it through with decoding the TLS.
I had a look at Apache with Rewrite but I am not sure it it only forwards the TLS-stream to another address or also decrypts it to pure HTTP.

You want to use a proxy connection, not a rewrite. Look at mod_proxy for Apache.

Maybe a little piece of config would be very helpful. I am not very familiar with it. THX!

What you are asking for is for the https webserver to act as a proxy to the back-end system. In the apache config, you will need is something similar to this in the proxy server's configuration:
ProxyPass         /  http://backend.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://backend.example.com/

Depending on your configuration, you might also need
ProxyPreserveHost On

You should not need to make any changes on the backend server.

And I need to put that into a virtual host section that handles SSL - right?

There’s a whole bunch of tools dedicated to this. What you are describing is a HTTP gateway otherwise known as a reverse proxy.
Firstly, if all you want is to offload TLS decryption, then it doesn’t need to be HTTP aware at all.  stunnel would get the job done just fine.
I’d personally recommend traefik. This will automatically make ACME requests for services like letsencrypt and is designed as a gateway from the ground up.
It can be configured to auto configure from docker, K8s, …
